# Function Pointer Declaration - what does __P do?

Tags: c, function, declaration, function-prototypes

The usual form of function pointer definitions is:

```
 int function(int, int);
 int (*ptr)(int, int);
```

but I saw a form today which I didn't understand. Can anyone explain this please?

```
int (*close)    __P((struct __db *));
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? (please add the tag to the question either way). Do you know what the `__P` macro is?

Comment: C, I have added tag. I don't know _P is macro. Our teacher ask us to learn the source file in berkeleyDB, but I am not good at C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `__P()` macro is usually used to support C implementations from the days of K&R C, when there were no prototypes (which were introduced to C with C89). Basically the logic is

```
#if SOME_LOGIC_TO_TEST_WHETHER_IMPLEMENTATION_SUPPORTS_PROTOTYPES
#  define __P(argument_list) argument_list
#else
#  define __P(argument_list) () 
#endif
```

Can you see how this works when applied to your example? Note that for this to work and not cause a syntax error, the argument list must include the parentheses of the ***function call***, not just the parentheses of the ***function-like macro***. Hence the double parentheses when the macro is used. That's probably the reason why it looks unusual.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Our teacher ask us to learn the source file in berkeleyDB. I was just stuck at that point.I am not good at C. I think I should learn more about C.

Comment: @Maybe_hu It's a great language, and much easier and more elegant than C++ (which is **not** a superset of C, but an entirely different language that happens to share some syntax and history).

Comment: So for me, what books or website should I read.Can you recommend some for me?

Comment: Only one book is essential: Kernighan, Ritchie, *The C Programming Language*, 2nd ed. These are the language authors. Anything else is opinion :-)

Comment: @Jens Except today's language is quite different. And it does not follow that the language authors are the best expositors. I actually think it's a good book, but that is due to its own merits rather than who the authors are.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The inventors of a language may not be the best writers of English, but I would regard them as the owners of the name.  If someone else slaps the name on a language which is radically different and is no longer suitable for the purposes that the original was invented I think it is entirely fair and reasonable to regard the latter as being a phony version of the former in the absence evidence that the original inventor would have approved of the change

Comment: @supercat You misunderstood my comment completely.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The language which is fashionable among the likes of clang and gcc with optimizations enabled but no other special options, is quite different from the one invented by Dennis Ritchie.  Whether C11 or K&R2 better describes "C" depends upon who one views as "owning" the name.  If K&R weren't co-written by Dennis Ritchie it would not be authoritative when it comes to differences between the language he invented and the modern pretender.

Comment: @supercat Yes, you still have not understood my comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Perhaps you can say what you meant?

Comment: @supercat I already did. I don't particularly think it's worth arguing about whether or not modern C is C or not. You assert that it is not. You seem to feel that only K&R can decide what C is. I am not of that view. Irrespective of whether or not they originated the language they may or may not be the best expositors. One does not follow from the other.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You also said you did not think the book's value came from the fact that it was co-authored by Dennis Ritchie.  To my mind, the book's importance stems from its authorship.  The same words written by anyone else without Ritchie's endorsement would not have the same significance.  The recognition of C89 as "real C" was dependent upon Ritchie's endorsement, and the book describes what Dennis Ritchie thought he was endorsing.

Comment: @supercat I don't think the same as you. I think the book's value comes from being superbly written. Not who wrote it.

Answer (score 9):

`__P()` is just a macro. On my system it is defined as follows (in `sys/cdefs.h`):

```
#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
#define __P(protos)     protos          /* full-blown ANSI C */
#else   /* !(__STDC__ || __cplusplus) */
#define __P(protos)     ()              /* traditional C preprocessor */
#endif  /* !__GNUC__ */
```

From this, it seems to be used to maintain compatibility with (very) old compilers.

Comment: used in function declarations such as for example this: `int functionname __P((int))` we hence will receive either *full-blown ANSI* `int functionname (int)` and for *traditional C preprocessor* `int functionname ()` which is valid since "early early K&R C" did have function declarations that if used only specified the return type but not the argument types, hence the substitution ot of the arguments to `()` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> The usual form of function pointer definitions is .... but I saw a
>   form today which I didn't understand.

There is nothing special here, no magic syntax. This is **not** a different *form* of function pointer declaration.

This is just the standard form of function pointer declaration, and `__P()` is a macro defined by one of the header files that you are using. So, find that macro definition to learn what its purpose is.

Comment: Or it may be defined conditionally to return either its argument or nothing.  The latter case is a legacy of K&R C, which didn't have prototypes.  Old libraries still contain this hack.

Comment: @Gene I was not trying to get into what `__P` does. In fact I've removed my speculation. The point I was trying to make is that this is not alternative syntax. It's just the standard syntax, and a macro.